# Making a header.php file

Tags: php, html

I want to make a header file, but **am not experienced with PHP** in almost any aspect. My uncle was telling me that I can use a header file with PHP, and that it was like a CSS with HTML.

The following is the HTML I want in my PHP:

```
<center><nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Arcade</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/arcade/action">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/arcade">Arcade</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/puzzle">Puzzle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/vehicle">Vehicle</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/violence">Violence</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/defense">Defense</a></li>
            <li><a href="/arcade/rpg">RPG</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Watch</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/watch/tv">TV Shows</a></li>
            <li><a href="/watch/movies">Movies</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Extras</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/news">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="/updates">Updates</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/support">Support</a></li>
</ul>
</nav></center>
```

How could I incorperate that into a header file?

I have looked at other websites such as W3Schools, but they don't seem to work. I think my main issue is that I am not sure how to put the HTML into the PHP document. When I do it, I try to type out the HTML as if it were header.html, only, ya know, it's not.

But anyways, if anybody could even just point me in the right direction of how to incorperate that HTML I included into a header.php file, and what to put in the html.

From what I have seen, the best scenario for including the PHP document in the HTML code is:

```
<html>
<?php
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
?>
```

Right now, I'm putting that HTML in every single page. This is restricting me from making navigational tab changes!

My website is http://www.gameshank.com/

Again, thanks in advanced, sooo much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah... the PHP [header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) command is used to output a HTTP header, so I'm really not sure what you're hoping to achieve via its use.

What you want to do is save your generic header HTML/PHP code into a *new* PHP file (perhaps called "header.php") and then include the contents of that file within each of your existing PHP pages via an [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) statement. For example:

```
<html>
<head><title>Sample HTML page</title></head>
<body>
    <?php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <h1>Page specific content</h1>
    <p>And stuff.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

By doing this, each page will automatically contain the contents of the `header.php` file (which will appear wherever you place the `include` statement) and any changes you require can simply be made to the `header.php` file.

Comment: So would I do something like this: <?php "my html I included" ?>

Comment: Yeah. <?php echo 'Hello World'; include 'menu.php'; ?> Try it out and see how it looks like.

Comment: @AustinBunker I've updated my answer to hopefully illustrate more clearly how'd you use the include statement.

Comment: @middaparka In the header.php document that I make, can I just put HTML in by the method of: <?php "html content" ?> or do I need to do something else (if I can use HTML5 in a PHP file)? And does my webpage have to be ex. index.php  or can it be index.html? Because my main issue is not knowing how to type the header.php document itself.

Comment: @AustinBunker In the `header.php` file, you can use both HTML and PHP. (Just because the file extension is .php doesn't mean it has to contain PHP - it just means that the web server will look for PHP code inside it.)

Comment: When I type the file, will it work if I, for example, typed this into the header.php: <?php <html><head><a href"/">Home</a></head> ?> Would that not be correct?

Comment: @AustinBunker In the `header.php` file, there's no need to have opening and closing tags (i.e.: `<?php` and `?>`) - these are only necessary if you want to use execute PHP. Incidentally, I'd recommend that you read the [PHP tutorial](http://www.php.net/tutorial) as it should clear some quite a bit of confusion for you.

Comment: Should the page that I include the PHP in be ex. index.php, or can it be an HTML file (ex. index.html) and still work?

Comment: @AustinBunker To use the include statement, the page must be parsed as PHP. (Most likely this will mean it has a .php extension on your system.)

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help! My last question is, do I need to know any other languages of script or code besides HTML and PHP for PHP, or can I jump right in?

Comment: @AustinBunker Nope, you just need PHP. (You don't even need HTML if you're not using PHP to create web pages.)

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can!

On your main page (Lets say index.php), on the top you can put in

```
<html>
    <?php
        include 'header.php';
    ?>
</html>
```

(Or whatever your header file is called.).

Put that HTML in header.php you want to include.

Comment: Your index should be a PHP file to include header.php.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use include like this

```
<?php 
include('header.php');
?>
```

or use require

```
<html>
<body>
<?php require("xxmenu.php"); ?>
<p>This is an example to show how to include PHP file!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

While you're at this, it's also a pretty good idea split the footer off of your page and place it in a seperate PHP file like you're doing with your header.

The point of this is it allows you to make changes to code that is featured in multiple pages throughout your site without having to go through every single page and make the same change.

For instance if you have "*Copyright (c) 2013 Blah Blah Blah*" at the bottom of 50 pages on your site, when 2014 rolls around you don't want to edit 50 pages to change 2013 to 2014. You'd just make it once in "footer.php".

And like the others have said, simply include the file in your pages.

```
<?php
   include 'footer.php';
?>
```